# animated gif with music, sound or voice-over

Tags: export, animation, sound, gif-format

I created a animated gif. This animation exist of 20 frames. The animation repeats after the last frame. [image]

I want to add music,sound or a voice-over to this animated gif. Who has a suggestion to do this in Wolfram Language.